# If $T$ is a symmetric bilinear form on vector space $V$, and let $U$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$, then $V=U+U^{\bot}$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Here is the full question:

> If $T$ is a symmetric bilinear form on vector space $V$, and let $U$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$, then $V=U+U^{\bot}$,

where $U^{\bot}$ is the orthogonal complement for $U$, given by $U^{\bot}=\{v \in V \mid T(u,v)=0\}$.

How does one prove that $V=U+U^{\bot}$?

We haven't introduced inner product spaces in class yet, and I understand that if $T$ was the inner product, standard proofs use: assume if $V \neq U + U^{\bot}$, there exists a vector $\alpha$ such it is orthogonal for all $\beta \in \text{span}(U,U^{\bot})$, implies $<\alpha, \beta>=0$, which implies $\alpha \in U^{\bot}$, contradiction.

But in this case, I cannot assume that $T$ is not an inner product? Are there any hints on how I can prove this statement?

Comment: You need more conditions on your bilinear form. The question as currently stated is not true, as the zero bilinear form and $U = V$ gives counter example.

Comment: If T wasn't the zero bilinear forms, are there any counterexample? What further conditions do you need? Are those the axioms of inner product spaces?

Comment: This is not true even if you assume that $T$ is non-degenerate (e.g. take some lightlike plane in Minkowski space). You do get at least that the dimensions of $U$ and $U^\perp$ add up to the dimension of $V$, provided either $T$ or $T|_U$ is non-degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not true in general. Take $A=\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ and define $T(u,v)=u^T A v$, the symmetric bilinear form.

Let $W=\text{span}\{(1,-1,0)\}$. Then the only vectors that fulfils $(a,b,c)\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{array}\right)$

is such that $(a,b,c) \left(\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right)=0$ has dimension 2, but since every vector in $W$ satisfies this equation as well, $W \subset W^{\bot}$ and their sum cannot be possibly equal to $V$.